# Google form edit link Collision Resolution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So over the past couple of weeks I've been working on trying to create a way of using google forms as a kind of editable pdf.  The idea is to have it be used as a group work order wherein the various people involved fill out the information pertaining to them as they acquire it.  Now I know this isn't exactly what forms are designed to do, but it seems to mostly be working.

The way I have it right now is that the initial user creates the initial response, which triggers a script on the form submission, that sends out an editable link via email to all of the contributors to the form.   Then whenever a contributor has information to add, they merely have to follow the link, make the change, submit the form and another email gets sent off alerting everyone of the edit.

The only problem with the system, however, comes when two users are filling out the edit link at the same time.  At that point the collision resolution (or potentially a lack of collision resolution) for the edit link appears to kick in.  The first user will submit and the form gets updated correctly, but once the second user submits, their changes override the changes of the first user.  Looking at this from a user standpoint this would be highly confusing.  Their change would appear to have been registered correctly, but in reality have been overwritten and discarded.

Now the ideal solution would be that the only changes that are overridden by the second user are those that actually have values in them.  I.e. if user one answers question A, and user two answers question B, and both answer question C, only question C is actually overridden, instead of A and C.

I initially thought that perhaps I could compare the two form responses and find some way of doing the collision detection on my own, but there seems to be no way to edit the actual form responses, to change the data on the edit link to match.  (Changing the spreadsheet values does not actually have any impact on the edit link itself)

So my question really boils down to is there a way to get this collision detection to work the way I am intending it to?  And if there isn't any way to do that, what would be the best way to trigger off a warning email when a collision does happen so that the users would at least know that something went wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could somehow use public `Cache` to determine if two people are editing at the same time.  [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/)  As soon as someone starts editing, put something into Cache. (like, TRUE)  It's public cache, so it's shared among users.  When the next person starts editing, if Cache value is TRUE, give a warning to the subsequent user.  Clear public Cache when update to spreadsheet is made.  I have no idea if this would work, just trying to "brainstorm" a solution.

Comment: I could definitely see that working as a solution to figuring out if data has been removed from the form, and using that to at the very least warn the users if something has been taken out (i.e. if values have been replaced through the collision).  So this definitely is helpful.

Comment: The Lock Service might help you: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/